# How can i extract specific range of lines in a .txt file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, text-extraction

Inside a text file i have a key text "Remuneração total". After i find the second match of this text line in the file, i should read and print 20 lines before and after this key line.

I've tried to find something like in internet, but i found nothing. Im pretty newbie at python programming so it has been a pretty hard job for me.

I only made into finding the first line that i want.

```
read_file = open(r"C:\Users\guerr\OneDrive\Documentos\PYTHON\TXT_FILES\file.txt", encoding='utf-8') # open file

lines = read_file.readlines()  # read all lines
for index, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate the list 

    if key in line: 
        print(line)
```

A
B
C
D
E
F
G

If my key was "D" and the range of lines was 2 before and after, it should return to me:

B
C
D
E
F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = '''
A
B
C
D
E
F
G'''

def custom_print(data, key, n):
    g = [data[i-2:i] + [val] + data[i+1:i+3] for i, val in enumerate(data) if key in val]
    return g[0] if g else []

data = lines.split()
print(custom_print(data, 'D', 2))
```

Prints:

```
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

If `key` is not found then `custom_print()` returns empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each letter was on a different line, you should iterate through the list and stop once you find the key, and record what line number you were at. Then, open it again and print the line if the distance between it and the key is less than or equal to the range.

Eg:

```py
key = "D"
lines = read_file.readlines()  # read all lines
for index, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate the list 

    if key in line: 
        key_line = index

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if abs(index - key_line) <= 2:
        print(line)
```